# Should I use specifications for simple validation logic?

Tags: validation, specifications

I have been reading about specifications lately and I am really keen on using them. However, I am afraid to overdo it.

For example, if I have a User entity with a phone number property, do I need to put the phone number specification test in the setter, or is the validation logic in the setter enough?

Thanks,
Phil

**UPDATE:**
For more context:
I think I would like the validation to be in the domain, and not in the presentation. I will implement the validation in presentation, but that will be more of a UI feature. The idea (i believe) is that the domain cannot be in an invalid state, nor can it rely on the presentation. I actually have a phone number Entity, and many entities have phone numbers, though I suppose this could value object, but that is another debate:)

I was just wondering if it overkill to use Specifications in Property setters. One advantage I could see is that Specifications can be shared between layers, ie the Presentation Layer, so that you can share the validation code.

As you can see, I am unsure if this is the right approach.

Much Thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 0):

You might look into the notion of pre and post conditions (invariants or design by contract).
Pre conditions are things that must be true for your function to operate correctly.
Post conditions are things that will be true when your function is complete and exits normally.

"user's phone number valid" is probably a good post condition to have for your setter function. However you have 2 choices for the pre-condition: (1) make it a precondition of your setter function that whatever is passed to it is valid, or (2) make a much looser pre condition to your setter function and perform the error checking in your setter function. Option (1) essentially passes responsibility for validation to the client. Option (2) endows your User entity with the responsibility for error handling.

I think the design you choose would depend on the bigger picture for your specific application.

Here are a few links for invariants and design by contract:
http://svengrand.blogspot.com/2008/11/preconditions-postconditions-invariants.html
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computer_Programming/Design_by_Contract

Comment: I will update my question with more detail. Those articles though are food for thought.